# What about these old houses?

Tags: set-identification, history

I recently inherited two old Lego buildings. Unfortunately I have virtually no information about the history of them other that they been part of the inventory of an old hardware store closed a decade ago.

By the look of them I would guess they are from the early 70's. The windmill-house has some of the old red, blue and yellow Technic gears in them and a custom non-Lego motor to make it spin forever.

Everything is glued together but there is apparently parts broken off in some places.

Some theories:

- Are they custom built in the old hardware store without blueprints?
- Are they part of some Lego advertising campaign?
- Are they actual Lego sets with a number to reference them?

Does anyone know anything about them? Would they be worth some money?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's most likely a promotional model. The door and frame shown on the bottom model was produced between 1973 and 1980. It very much looks like a promotional model from the 70's, as does the first model.

Comment: Was the 2nd house on TV years ago?

Comment: You may be onto something. It looks familiar to me too. But I was thinking it looks similar too something I saw in a Lego idea-book from the late 70's.

Answer (score 3):

The top picture is for sure a model created from single elements, and is not any Lego model.

Your lower model looks like a combination from 5 or 6 different houses. I recognize the Taxi station (Red with blue roof on the bottom), Bakery (Yellow and blue roof on top of that).

Try brickset.com and look for the older catalogues.

Comment: Are you thinking about these? http://brickset.com/sets/368-1/Taxi-Garage and http://brickset.com/sets/361-1/Tea-Garden-Cafe

Comment: Yep, that's them. Cannot really trace the white houses, they had so many of them in those years. But if you scan a bit more you might be able to get some clues. They should also have lots of building instructions, so you can try to get them back to the original state if you want.

Comment: Apart from the wall and roof colors the buildings don't seem to match. The floor plans and the locations of windows and doors are quite different from the sets.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your three bullet points:
Very likely.
Possibly.
Highly unlikely.

Sad that they are glued, but they are still pretty cool. You might get some money for them if you find a buyer.

Regardless, thanks for posting the pictures, I love the techniques for the big grey roof.